# apache camel-processor being called repetedly

Tags: java, apache-camel

i wrote a code to transfer a csv file from one folder to another and remove the last column while transferring it but while I am running it the done appears at console many times but the route is working correctly.Is this due to the Threading model of Apache camel allocating multiple threads?

```
from("file:///home/Laptop/Desktop/java/DemoFeed/1?
antInclude=*.gz&move=processed").unmarshal().gzip().process(new 
Processor() {

public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception 
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String body=exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
String row[]=body.split("\n");
for(int rowIndex=0;rowIndex<row.length-1;rowIndex++)
{
  String rowIterator=row[rowIndex];
  String rowEntries[]=rowIterator.split(",");
  for(int index=0;index<rowEntries.length-1;index++)
  {
    builder.append(rowEntries[index]);
    if(index!=rowEntries.length-2)
    builder.append(",");
  }
   builder.append("\n");
   exchange.getOut().setBody(builder.toString());
   System.out.println("done");
  }
  }
}).setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,constant("name.csv")).marshal().zipFile().to("file:2?fileName=name.csv.zip");
```

Comment: Isn't this just a case of moving the println outside of the for loop? Likewise with setting the exchange body, you only need to do that once you've finished processing the file content.

Comment: @JamesNetherton thank you i didn't even notice this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @james-netherton already commented: just take the two lines

```
exchange.getOut().setBody(builder.toString());
System.out.println("done");
```

out of the outer for-loop. You overwrite your message body and print out `done` after every processed row.